# Trouble with loops.C++ simple game

Tags: c++

I've been working on a simple c++ game.I am having trouble making the game repeat functions.I want to make it to do something like this: 1.Enter what you want to do 2.Execute the choise 3.Display Results 4.Then repeat from 1.Also i know i have a lot of unused classes, functions, variables etc, but that because its not finished.(Using Code::Blocks)

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main();

//variables
const int X = 0;
const int Y = 10;
const int Z = 0;
int X1 = X;
int Y1 = Y;
int Z1 = Z;
int Input;
int Input2;
int test = 1;

int Menu()
{
    while (test == 1) {
        test--;
        cout << "Please type what you want to do." << endl;
        cin >> Input;
    }
    return Input;
    //deciding what they want to do.
}

int Calculating()
{
    //Calculating Function(Unused)
}

class Player {
public:
    void Movement()
    {
        //the loop that activates when the Input == 1
        cout << "2 - Move" << endl;
        do {
            cin >> Input2;
            int test = 1;
            Menu();
        } while (Input2 < 3 && Input2 > 1);

        switch (Input2) {
        case 1:
            cout << "You moved" << endl;
        }
    }
    void Attack()
    {
        //the loop that activates when the Input == 2
        cout << "1 - Sword Dance" << endl;
        do {
            cin >> Input2;
            int test = 1;
            Menu();
        } while (Input2 < 3 && Input2 > 1);

        switch (Input2) {
        case 1:
            cout << "DMG" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
};

class Enemy {
    //Enemy class(Unused)
};

int main()
{
    Input = Menu();

    Player Pl;
    //if the chosen number was 1 it will make the Player move.
    //if the chosen number was 2 it will make the Player attack.
    if (Input == 1) {
        Pl.Movement();
    }
    else if (Input == 2) {
        Pl.Attack();
    }

    Menu();
    //calling the Menu function
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

A `do-while` loop in the main, without the `while` (and `test--`) in Menu()?

(`do-while` so you can choose to end the loop displaying the menu at least one time)